# Programmatically download an attachment via Mantis SOAP API?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap-client, mantis

Successfully using the [Mantis SOAP API](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:faq) (aka "MantisConnect") from C#, I can successfully read an issue and also get the `download_url` field.

When trying to download the attachment by something like this:

```
using (var request = new WebClient())
{
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    return request.DownloadData(mantisAtt.download_url);
}
```

it "downloads" a HTML page with the login screen instead of the binary attachment content.

**So my question is:**

How can I *programmatically* download an attachment for an issue in Mantis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was on the completely wrong track. Instead of following the download URL being returned I now use the function `mc_issue_attachment_get` and everything works as expected.

So to solve, do *not* download from the URL but simply use the intended SOAP API function.

*(I found the solution after posting my question to the "mantisbt-soap-dev" mailing list and got a fast reply)*